# Foursquare API 404 error: Endpoint not found

Tags: android, foursquare

I am trying to do a GET request using the foursquare checkin endpoint.  I'm getting back a 404 error which is endpoint not found.  Any help with why that could be happening would be great!

```
        try {      
        URI url = new URI("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/user/self/checkins?oauth_token="+TokenStore.get().getToken()+"&v=20140219");

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

        int responceCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        Log.i(TAG, "Responce = "+ responceCode);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The endpoint is **users/self**, not user/self, which you have. Just a typo :)